# Listview insertion mark invisible when there's groups

Tags: .net, vb.net

**Update:** (*Please vote to close*) This question is unresolved, and is likely a list view bug. It can be replicated by using the example code from the MSDN link below, and adding this code after the list view initialization code:

```
        myListView.View = View.Details;
        myListView.Columns.Add("Column1");
        myListView.Groups.Add("group", "group");
```

*I no longer need to solve this issue, and vote to close this question*

---

I'm using drag-drop to order items in a list view, this work flow is then saved into a database. This is in .Net 2.0

I use [Insertion Marks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx62xfd2(VS.80).aspx) to indicate where the dragged item will be dropped, and the example given on the MSDN page works great, but when the list view contains items inside groups, then the insertion mark fails to draw.

From the drop behavior it almost seems like the groups interfere with the coordinate system. Has anybody else noticed this, am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a list view bug. It has been 16 months since asking this, and 4 months since voting to close. Still no resolution from Microsoft or community sites. I am answering as [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519).